# Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException for non-annotated field

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is my POJO, a simple student class.

```java
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Entity(name = "Students")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9182600037012718128L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    private List<Homework> homework; // <-- the problematic line

    public Student(){
    }

    public getId(){return id;}
    public setId(long id){this.id = id;}

    public getName(){return name;}
    public setName(String name){this.name = name;}

    public getHomework(){return homework;}
    public setHomework(List<Homework> homework){this.homework = homework;}
}
```

Unfortunately, even though the `homework` field is not annotated (since I currently do not want to map it to my DB), I get this exception when running my application:

```java
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Students, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(homework)]
```

This is my hibernate-config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.show.sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.test.entity.Student</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make non mapped field as `transient`, to make hibernate not try to map it with DB

```
private transient List<Homework> homework;
```

or you can annotate it with `@javax.persistence.Transient` annotation

```
@Transient
private List<Homework> homework;
```

One feature of hibernate is, it tries to map all the fields of Entity class with the corresponding columns of the table. So for the variable `homework`, it searches for the corresponding column with the same name *"homework"*  (case -insensitive) in the mapped table.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property), and it says

> Every non static non transient property (field or method depending on
>   the access type) of an entity is considered persistent, unless you
>   annotate it as @Transient. Not having an annotation for your property
>   is equivalent to the appropriate @Basic annotation.

Comment: thanks for the fast response... but why is it mapped anyway?? Shouldn't Hibernate map only annotated fields?